# Grab two parts of a single, short string

Tags: python, regex, id3

I'm looking to fill a python `dict` with `TAG`:`definition` pairs, and I'm using RegExr http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to write the regex

My first step is to parse a line, from http://www.id3.org/id3v2.3.0, or http://pastebin.com/VJEBGauL and pull out the ID3 tag and the associated definition. For example the first line:

```
4.20    AENC    [#sec4.20 Audio encryption]
```

would look like this `myDict = {'AENC' : 'Audio encryption'}`

To grab the tag name, I've got it looking for at least 3 spaces, then 4 characters, then 4 spaces: `{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{4} {4}` That part is easy enough.

The second part, the definition, is not working out for me. So far, I've got `(?<=(\[#.+?)) A` Which should find, but not include the `[#` as well as an indeterminded set of characters until it finds: `_A`, but it's failing. If I remove `.+?` and replace `_A` with `s` it works out alright. What is going wrong? *The underscores represent spaces, which don't show up on SO.

**How do I grab the definition, ie,`(Audio encryption)` of the ID3v2 tag from the line, using RegEx?**

edit: Thanks to the answers I got from `mVChr`, I wrote this for everyone else trying to do the same thing: http://pastebin.com/0nT74dpB

Comment: For a file that's space delimited like that, it's almost always better to not use regex for the first part. `line.split()` will serve this purpose nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use capturing groups `()` to pull out only what you need:

```
import re
line = '4.20    AENC    [#sec4.20 Audio encryption]'
full_match = re.search(r'^\S+\s+(\S+)\s+\[#\S+ (.*?)\]', line)
dict_key = full_match.group(1)   # 'AENC'
id3v2_tag = full_match.group(2)  # 'Audio encryption'
```

Comment: Works wonderfully, thank you. It had me confused for a minute, since RegExr uses a different syntax than `re` does. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? Notice how I just used `line.split()` for the first part.

```
import re
line = '4.20    AENC    [#sec4.20 Audio encryption]'

_, tag, arguments = line.split(None, 2)
m = re.match(r"\[\S+ (.*)\]", arguments)
myDict[tag] = m.groups()[0]
```

Of course since the ID3 grammar appears pretty simple, you could probably do the entire thing without regular expressions:

```
_, tag, arguments = line.split(None, 2)
myDict[tag] = arguments.strip(" []").split(None, 1)[1]
```

Of course, if `line` is empty, python will raise a `ValueError` when you try to unpack the values into `_, tag, arguments`. One way to remedy this is to test each line *before* running the above code:

```
for line in file_object:
    if line.strip():
        #the above code here.
```

Comment: That's a pretty neat way of solving it too. Thank you!

Comment: +1. The only problem with this is that if he gets, say, a blank line, he'll get an exception unpacking a tuple of the wrong length. This is of course easy to work around in various different ways, but it's worth mentioning, because people run into that problem all the time (and often post on SO asking why their code fails, showing the first 3 perfectly valid lines, and not showing the last empty line…).

Comment: I actually just ran into that problem with parsing the `ID3v2` stuff, instead of the `v3` docs. I dunno how clean it is, but all I did was strip each line, and just catch the `attributeError`'s and print them,  so you can make sure you're not losing a line. Effectively ignoring blank lines.

Comment: @TankorSmash: It's more clear (and arguably slightly more pythonic) to test the lines before attempting to parse them, rather than catching the error after the fact. See my edit

Comment: Cool! Since `''` is returned by the `strip` and it's equivalent to `False`. And I'm not catching any unexpected errors. Understood,  thanks.

Comment: This is nice, and it allows for obvious extensions (e.g., if you want to skip "comment" lines that start with '#') in an obvious way.